# Unable to pass custom datatype as parameter to wcf service

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I created one custom library project and it have Employee class to hold employee information.

```
namespace Test.SampleLib
{

    public class Employee
    {

        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

        public double EmployeeSalary {get; set; }
    }
}
```

I added the Employee class library to the WCF service

```
public Test.SampleLib.Employee GetDataUsingDataContract(Test.SampleLib.Employee composite)
{

    return composite;
}
```

I tried to consume the service and access the method GetDataUsingDataContract()

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client objServiceRef = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
Test.SampleLib.Employee objEmployee = new SampleLib.Employee();
objEmployee.EmployeeName = "Kumar";
objEmployee.EmployeeSalary = 30000;

objServiceRef.GetDataUsingDataContract(objEmployee); //Gives errror
```

The error is

```
'Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Test.SampleLib.Employee' to 'Test.Web.ServiceReference1.Employee'
```

Comment: Did you try to declare your variable as Test.Web.ServiceReference1.Employee instead of Test.SampleLib.Employee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have  `[DataContract]` and  `[DataMember]` attributes on custom data types and its properties you want to expose.

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public double EmployeeSalary {get; set; }
    }
```